# java Printing through dot matrix, skipping page

Tags: java, printing, dot-matrix

I am trying to print through java on dot matrix printer with custom page size height 10 inches  by 6 inches width. It is working fine on laser printer, but on dot matrix printer after printing 10 inches next page gets skipped around 3 inches more.

Comment: 1- Make sure that your `setDefaultCloseOperation` isn't set to `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` would be more appropritate.  From there, simply call `setVisible(false)` on the frame to hide it.

Comment: There is no such thing as a jform.  Please copy/paste these things instead of making them up.

Comment: @MadProgrammer  *"`HIDE_ON_CLOSE` would be more appropritate"* Or `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143287/how-to-best-position-swing-guis/7143398#7143398).  But see also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's difficult to ascertain what the intentions of the OP actually is, but yes `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` would also be a valid option.

Comment: On click at jbutton action is performed. i am calling system.exit(0) in this button action performed. i dont want to close my application. i want to jst hide that form.

Comment: *"..i am calling system.exit(0) in this button action performed."*  Did you read the JavaDocs for [`System.exit(n)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29)?  *"Terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine.."*  Don't you think you should remove that line of code?!?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson i removed it. but i want to hide it after task is performed. How do i do that?

Comment: *For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the command `setVisible(boolean visible)`!

- http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JFramesetVisiblebooleanvisible.htm